# Crontab is delayed by 2 hours

Tags: linux, cron, shell

I have got a problem with two crontabs that execute some operations on my website: the first one run a command every 3 minutes and the second one at 5am in this way:

```
m    h  dom mon dow command
0    5  *   *   *   command1
*/3  *  *   *   *   command2
```

I suppose that works correctly and my website confirms it.

The problem is when this crontab is executed, in fact the first crontab runs at 3am and not a 5am (there aren't problem of local time).

I can't undestand where is the problem.

Thank you

Comment: My server use the correct local time but the website not.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you was changed timezone on server, you must restart cron daemon.
2. Maybe runnning anacron? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron